# How to return reference to non-modifiable object in C#

Tags: c#, object, reference, return

I have class like this:

```
static private Dictionary<int, String> states;

static public Dictionary<int, String> GetStates()
{
  if (states != null)
  {
    return states;
  }
  else
  {
    states = new Dictionary<int, string>();
    states.Add(1, "State 1 name.");
    states.Add(2, "State 2 name");
    // etc
  }
  return states;
}
```

Returned dictionary should be non-modifiable.
Looking for best way to solve this problem.

Comment: Literally a duplicate of Marcin's yesterday.. will find and post here..

Comment: Here we go: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20984980/how-can-i-safely-return-listt-from-method-property-declared-as-ienumerablet I guess in your case the idea is to return a `ReadOnlyDictionary<T, T2>`. MSDN Link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg712875(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: It's not a duplicate, as in this case, the OP needs a dictionary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you change your return type to `IDictionary<TKey, TValue>`, then you should be able to return a `ReadOnlyDictionary`:

```
static public IDictionary<int, String> GetStates()
{
  if (states != null)
  {
    return new ReadOnlyDictionary(states);
  }
```

Comment: And to be explicit you can change the return type to `IReadOnlyDictionary<TKey, TValue>`